# Storying SSH commands result to a variable?

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm ssh'ing to a server to read times out of a log file. It's failing and I'm wondering where I'm going wrong. I reckon I'm not escaping something correctly?

```
LastBroken= $(ssh ${UserLogin}@${ServerName} -p${PortNumber} "grep 'BROKEN' /scripts/SSHtoDo.log  | tail -1 | head -1 | awk '{ print \$2, \$3, \$4, \$5, \$6 }'")


LastRestarted= $(ssh ${UserLogin}@${ServerName} -p${PortNumber} "grep 'RESTARTED' /scripts/SSHtoDo.log  | tail -1 | head -1 | awk  '{ print \$2, \$3, \$4, \$5, \$6 }'")
```

Comment: Grep goes to the stdout of the host I think You could try echo the whole thing like `'echo $(grep .....)'`

Comment: It was the space between the varname= and $ that did the damage
`...Broken= $(ssh...`

Comment: Oops... Yes or that :D